# Pattern Tokenizer Factory doesn't work properly

Tags: solr, lucene, schema

I'm trying parse input line using PatternTokenizerFactory.

So according to doc:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternTokenizerFactory.html

My schema looks like:

```
    <fieldType name="text_ptn" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(&quot;bbb&quot;: &quot;)([[a-zA-Z ]+)" group="2"/>
     </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

So, this pattern should work: https://regex101.com/r/9Ep6qO/6

According to schema I'm trying to get value of from particular part of the "test" field ('bbb'). As I understand now I can search doc just writing in Solr "test":"Acc Hs"
But I can search only using such construction: "test":"'bbb': 'Acc Hs'"

My solution was to split this input and then use the filter:

```
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(.*\&quot;bbb\&quot;: \&quot;)" />

    <filter class="solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory" 
           pattern="(^[a-zA-Z ]+)"
           preserve_original="false"/>
```

So, could you explain why the first option isn't working.(There were no difference when I put e.g. group="1")

Comment: It should work if you escape the quotes in the first pattern like in the second one.

Comment: Also remember that the tokenizer is applied on both input and output (searching and indexing) unless you say otherwise. This might require your query to match the expected pattern as well. Use the Analysis page under Solr admin to test both your query and indexed content and to see how the values are processed in each analysis step.

Comment: @ericLavault ok, as i said i tried to run the same example as in documentation: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternTokenizerFactory.html
So it searches as in my example only by 'bbb'

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for advice. When I try to use Analysis in example in documentation it just giving no info about value "bbb" but gives info about 'bbb' where the text is just bbb. But as i mention I can't search just by typing "bbb"

Comment: Which seems to indicate that the problem is that the pattern match fails on query. You can use `<analyzer type="index">` and `<analyzer type="query">` to have separate chains for indexing and querying. See Analysis Phases here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analyzers - I'll add a proper answer if that truly is it.